# jquery next() function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have a css animation that does two things, one adds an opacity and two creates a slideUp animation when the user hovers on the specified area. I am having an issue with adding and removing the opacity. I am not sure where i have gone wrong. Below is a snippet of my code.

html

```
<body id="body" class="preload">
        <div class="box">
        <div class="trigger">hhh</div>
            <div class="overlay animated">
                <h1>box 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="box">
<div class="trigger">hhh</div>
      <div class="overlay animated">
            <h1>box 1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

js

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("window").load(function(){
            $("#body").removeClass("preload");
        });

            $(".trigger").hover(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.next(".overlay").removeClass("fadeInDown", 1000).addClass("fadeInUp", 1000);
            }); 

            $(".trigger").mouseleave(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.next(".overlay").removeClass("fadeInUp", 1000).addClass("fadeInDown", 1000);
            }); 

            $(".box").hover(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.next(".copy-bg").addClass("opacity");
            });

            $(".box").mouseleave(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.next(".copy-bg").removeClass("opacity");
            });

    </script>
```

css

```
.trigger{
width:100%; height: 100%;
position: relative;
 }

 .box{
width: 300px; height: 300px;
background: red; 
@include inline-block;
margin: 0 2px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
  }

.overlay{
height: 100%; width: 100%;
bottom: -200px;
position: absolute;

h1{
    color: #fff;
}
  }

 .copy-bg{
@include opacity(0.50);
width: 100%; height: 100%;
background: #000;
position: absolute;
display: none;
   }

.opacity{
display: block;
  }

.copy{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
   }

  .animated{
@include transition-duration(1s ease);
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-o-animation-fill-mode: both;
   }

  .animated.hinge{
@include transition-duration(1s);
   }

 .fadeInUp{
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
display: block;
  }



  .animated{-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-ms-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-ms-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;}.animated.hinge{-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-ms-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;}@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}   100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
}
```

}

```
      @-moz-keyframes fadeInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
}
    }

  @-o-keyframes fadeInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateY(20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
}
   }

  @keyframes fadeInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
  }

.fadeInUp {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
-moz-animation-name: fadeInUp;
-o-animation-name: fadeInUp;
animation-name: fadeInUp;
 }
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}
   }

  @-moz-keyframes fadeInDown {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
}
    }

   @-o-keyframes fadeInDown {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateY(-20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
}
    }

     @keyframes fadeInDown {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
  }

 .fadeInDown {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
-moz-animation-name: fadeInDown;
-o-animation-name: fadeInDown;
animation-name: fadeInDown;
  }
```

Comment: first off, you want to put all that jquery code inside `$(document).ready() { // your code here });` Then come back here if that doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: ".copy-bg" I cant see this class in your html ?

Comment: @rgin i said it was a snippet, obv i have $(document).ready(). Aveendra, .copy-bg is an added class

Comment: please share the code where the `copy-bg` is added

Comment: @ArunPJohny <div class="box">
  <div class="copy-bg"></div>
 <div class="trigger">hhh</div>
  <div class="overlay animated">
     <div class="copy"><h1>box 1</h1></div>
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: Nope. not really all that obvious. Especially after the fact that you enclosed it inside a `<script></script>` tag.

Comment: If you find that a jQuery method doesn't seem to be doing what you think it should be how about consulting the documentation for that method? Also, please add the relevant html to your question, don't post it in a comment.

Comment: @nnnnnn it sure is. Arun P Johny hit the nail on the head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you ca see `copy-bg` is not the next element of `box`, it is a child

```
        $(".box").hover(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.children(".copy-bg").addClass("opacity");
        });

        $(".box").mouseleave(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.children(".copy-bg").removeClass("opacity");
        });
```